# If $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are p.s.d matrices with $A_{ii} \geq B_{ii}$ for all $i$, can we say that $A-B$ is p.s.d

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

This is not a homework problem.

I know that any linear combination of positive semidefinite matrices is also positive semidefinite. On the other hand, if $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are both positive semidefinite, then $A-B$ is not positive semidefinite in general.(from my understanding)

Now, what if for each $i=1, \dots,n$, we have $(A)_{ii} \geq (B)_{ii}$, i.e. each diagonal entry in $A$ is greater than or equal to the diagonal entry in $B$ for all $i$. Can we say that $A-B$ is positive semidefinite? Note that all matrices mentioned above are symmetric.

Any reference or hint is appreciated.

Comment: It is not true, $-I$ is not PSD. It is true that any **convex** combination is PSD.

Comment: Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, both are positive semi definite but $A-B$ has an eigenvalue of $-1$.

Comment: $$\pmatrix{10&9\cr9&10\cr}-\pmatrix{9&1\cr1&9\cr}=\pmatrix{1&8\cr8&1\cr}$$